# datetime in bigint field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a date time to a bigint field and then display it in a gridview using SQL query...
First im not sure how to add the date time in big int field

so im using

```
long s= DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

which is storing a sample value like  633896886277130000

then i want get only the date from it using the SQl Select statement and display on gridview..

```
SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName,
   MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, **MachineGroups.TimeAdded**,
   MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS 'No. of PCs'
FROM MachineGroups
FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID
GROUP BY MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName,
   MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted"
```

can i use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
'2008-05-20T06:00:00'));
```

**long TimeAdded = (DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() - 116444736000000000) / 10000000;
i get this value
1254157826**

Comment: why are you trying to store it as a BIGINT instead of DATETIME?

Comment: i dont know how to inplement the convert statement with my SQL query..
I cannot use the DATETIME thats the condition.. I know date time would have been easier.... Please help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving .NET Ticks in your MachineGroups.TimeAdded field, then it can be converted to SQL DateTime like below.  (Subtract Ticks of 1900-01-01 and divide by ticks per day)

Select convert(datetime, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000)/864000000000)
FROM MachineGroups

If you want just date use FLOOR:

Select convert(datetime, FLOOR((MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000)/864000000000))
FROM MachineGroups

**EDIT** You will get error if ticks is invalid you can use this for error checking:

Select CASE WHEN MachineGroups.TimeAdded < 599266080000000000 THEN null ELSE convert(datetime, (MachineGroups.TimeAdded - 599266080000000000)/864000000000) END
FROM MachineGroups

Comment: i get an error if i put this

 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: If field is less than 599266080000000000 (1900-01-01) you will get that error.

Comment: hi i tried using floor
but i get 

9/27/2009 12:00:00 AM

as u see the time is also coming... but the time is wrong...

if i use the query above the Floor 

i get---9/27/2009 10:50:27 PM

Here time is right but i dont want to display it..

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to get the data in ticks only to your asp.net code, then convert it to whatever format you want.

Comment: but the convertion part im not getting... please could u help me in that

Comment: The `DateTime` class contains methods for converting to/from ticks. You even quote one of them in your question. It is better practice to convert data in your DAL code rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're storing ticks, and then it looks like you're converting them back in your second example as if they're seconds, which is going to be way off. You'd have to treat them as either ticks or seconds, but not both. If you have the flexibility and you don't need the added precision, I imagine seconds would be much easier to work with. Also, it doesn't looks like SQL Server supports Ticks, so if you need that level of precision, you'll need to convert it to milliseconds, or something of that nature.

Then, you'd convert back using:

```
SELECT DATEADD(seconds, YourValueFromTable, CONVERT(DATETIME, 0))
```

Obviously, if you're not using seconds, substitute the appropriate keyword.

Comment: can u suggest how to get in seconds and not in tics.. and then display the date from it using the SQL select statement... it will be very helpful.. thanks

Comment: First you say you want to display the datetime in a GridView, then you say you want the datetime in the SQL resultset instead. Which is it?

Comment: the select query as above is for a gridview as seen above... and it displays records in a gridview...
so i i get the SQL query il get the display..

Comment: It's better practice to return the ticks value in the SQL and convert it to a date/time value when rendering the GridView.

Comment: How are you getting the data into the GridView? Are you using data binding? If so, use a TemplateColumn instead of a BoundColumn for the date/time, then you can precisely control the binding expression to do the data conversion.

Comment: i just converted my time added column into template...
Plese could u tell me no how to do the data converdion....

Answer (score 0):

1 second is 10,000,000 ticks.  If you want to work in ticks in the application, you'll need to remove the "T"s and multiple by 10,000,000:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
'2008-05-20 06:00:00'))*10000000
```